# Flutter_CLI: Because every version of flutterfire_cli depends on xml >=5.3.0 which requires SDK version >=2.14.0 <3.0.0, flutterfire_cli is forbidden

Tags: windows, flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-cli

I am trying to install firebase_cli for my flutter project, but it tells me:

> "Because every version of flutterfire_cli depends on xml >=5.3.0 which
> requires SDK version >=2.14.0 <3.0.0, flutterfire_cli is forbidden"

Showing that my SDK version is **2.13.4** and it needs **2.14.0** onwards.

I went to flutter console as administrator and run `choco upgrade dart-sdk`. It told me I now have version **v2.17.3**.

However, I still get the same problem in flutterfire_cli.

Things I've tried:

- creating a `.bashrc` file with the line `export PATH="$PATH": "C:\Users\sjrol\OneDrive\Documentos\flutter\.pub-cache\bin"` in it (it is the route flutter console told me to save).
- creating a system environment variable inside *PATH* that points to my dart folder [image], with the newer version.
- In my pubspec.yaml file I've got [image].

Then rebooted the PC. Same problem. No idea of what's happening.

`Dart pub global` and `choco upgrade` results (running the firebase console as administrator):
[image]

Flutter doctor (I don't use android studio so no problem, and the android status problem is something I've been facing for a long time and has never given me any problem. Maybe it still has something to do with this?).
[image]

I can tell I'm working with the new dart version in my VSCode now, thanks to the new features it has, but firebase still won't let me install CLI. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. Change your sdk version in *pubspec.yaml* to **sdk: ">=2.17.3 <3.0.0"**
2. Run `dart --version` to make sure the new path is working
3. Run `flutter clean`
4. Run the app

Comment: Just did it. Didn't work sadly...

Comment: App gives me "[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: [core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()" because I got no Firebase_CLI, and still have the old version according to the dart command

Comment: `.bashrc` file is for linux based systems. For windows installation of Flutter, check [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows). And I'd recommend to uninstall the old Flutter & Dart and install the newest. For the _Firebase initializeApp()_ error, it's probably that you have to initialize Firebase inside `void main()` or something like that, or a missing package that you have to get from _pub_.

Comment: I'll try that. And no, I have the initializeApp(), and gives that error, according to some other forums from some months ago, because I dont have Firebase_CLI, which is why I was trying to install it. I may just unistall it all and get all of it from zero.

Comment: After many hours, I reinstalled the whole SDK and, after some more error, could make it. I'll accept you answer as thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you Flutter or Dart SDK is out of date.
Hit the following commands:

1. Run `brew upgrade dart` on mac or `flutter upgrade` on flutter cli for windows.
2. Run `flutter upgrade`

This should have done the needful. Now you can go ahead with

3. `dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli`